# Reapply for NL visa

Tags: schengen-visas

I just would like to ask when can i reapply for visiting visa in the Netherlands? I have been there last December 19,2016 til February 18,2017. I lately just read about "90 days in 180 days period". What does that mean? I checked my recent visa and saw the dates from December 17,2016 til April 1, 2017( 105 days). Can i apply for reentry visa this May? I hope you can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are already a few questions about Schengen visa and the 90/189  rule on the site. Did you try searching?

Comment: i did but none of them discussed about the dates from the visa itself.

Comment: It is not the dates on the visa, it is the dates of the days you actually spend in the Schengen zone. Feed them into the calculator you find in the duplicate question (in its accepted answer.)